# Powershell - Get Contents of a file and display until string exists

Tags: powershell, do-while

I have a log file that is continuously written to until it reaches a certain size.  When this happens, a line is written stating that the log is bring rotated and giving the name of the new file (example: 2022-10-06 09:30:00.255 Rotating log file, new log file will be: 20221006-093000.txt).  My end goal is to have a working PS script to automatically load this new file, but for now, I am trying to write a script that displays the content of the file live (using -wait), nested inside a Do While loop, and once a string containing the word "Rotating" exists, exit (or write something, whatever).  My code currently:

```
$string = Get-Content "C:\20221007-124000.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "Rotating"
Do {
(Get-Content "C:\20221005-062000.txt" -wait)
}
Until ($string -ne $null)

Write-Host "Exit"
```

This doesn't error out, but it doesn't ever appear to do anything.  If I remove the loop, the get-content "path" -wait works perfectly.  But inside the loop, it doesn't write anything to the console.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$String` is set once, outside your loop. So if its value is `$null` going into your loop, your loop will never exit. Also confused by the various text file names. Why one file outside the loop and a different one inside?

Comment: Regarding the null, great point.  So I'll need to rearrange it some.  Ignore the different file names.  That was just a failure during removing PI.

Comment: This code will never reach the Until check because it will stay forever in the "get-content loop".   If you want to react to the output from `Get-Content -Wait`  you must use the pipeline.  `Get-Content 'C:\20221005-062000.txt' -Last 0 -Wait | Foreach-Object { if ($_ -match $string) { "Found matching line - '$_'" ; break }` .  One note about using `break` to end the Get-Content loop, it will not only break out of the Get-Content loop but it will also exit the calling script and nothing following will run.  If you are running only this code then this is not an issue.

Comment: Daniel, made a few tweaks but seems to work well.  Now just need to load the new log file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you:

```
#-wait read file every second and outputs new lines
Get-Content $Logfile.FullName -wait | %{
    #Verify if new line matches the pattern: \d{8} = 8 digits
    If ($_ -match 'new log file will be: \d{8}-\d{6}\.txt'){
        #Output matching line
        write-host $_
    }
}
```

This will read once per second the file and verifies for each new line if it matches the pattern, if so it outputs the matching line.

To rotate the logfile you could do something like this:

```
#Specify path to logfile
$Logfile = get-item 'C:\tmp\test.txt'
#You may add a condition to fulfill otherwise it runs forever
while ($true){
    #-wait read file every second and output new lines
    Get-Content $Logfile.FullName -wait | %{
        #Verify if new line matches the pattern: \d{8} = 8 digits
        If ($_ -match 'new log file will be: \d{8}-\d{6}\.txt'){
            #Extract new filename
            $newFileName = $matches[0] -replace 'new log file will be: '
            #Build new path 
            $newPath = join-path -Path $Logfile.Directory -ChildPath $newFileName
            #Set variable to $null so that we can use it as condition (until)
            $Logfile = $null
            #Try every 500ms to get Logfile
            do {
                $LogFile = get-item -path $newPath -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
                start-sleep -Milliseconds 500     
            }
            until ($Logfile)
            #Use continue to exit get-content -wait and restart procedure with new path
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Toni.  Somewhat works, but it doesn't actually output the log file live.  It just sits there with no return

Comment: yes it simply rotates the log, just add ```write-host $logfile```one line  before get-content  $logfile.fullname to see the rotation. or better said once the logfile contains the string 'new log file will be: \d{8}-\d{6}\.txt' it extracts the new logfilename out of the string and reads the new logfile once available. you could also add ```write-host $newfilename``` one line after $newfilename = $matches[0].... to see something